# Shutdown and restart stuck on "Starting LightDM Display Manager"

Tags: release-freya, boot, system, shutdown

It's been a couple of days since I used Elementary OS and it worked as smooth as possible but then all of a sudden I started having this problem. Whenever I restart or shutdown my notebook, it keeps getting stuck in here where it says:

```
*Starting LightDM Display Manager
*Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up
[17370.126206] [drm:intel_set_cpu_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pipe A 
[17370.126267] [drm:intel_cpu_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
```

**Here's a picture of the problem:**

[image]

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster's temporary fix was to restart `lightdm` via the command line, which would be:  
**`sudo service lightdm restart`** OR **`sudo systemctl restart lightdm`**

You can also try [reconfiguring lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/q/365719/49899).

Answer (score 0):

I started to receive same problem. I used oibaf/graphics-drivers ppa.

To fix this i've logged in through grub recovery mode, then purged that ppa